# Temporary Public URL for IBM Bluemix Object Storage Service with NodeJs

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud, openstack, object-storage

Use case:  File uploaded in to IBM Object Storage. Now want to provide temporary access via a signed URL that will expire after a certain delay.

Only SWIFT are being supported officially, need a workaround that works with JAVASCRIPT -> NodeJs.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? I was stuck in this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

---

You have to install SWIFT CLI and set a temporary key for your credentials.

This step is super important and CAN ONLY BE DONE BY USING THE SWIFT CLI as there is now way to do that currently with Bluemix Console.

STEP 0 - ************ MANDATORY *************
INSTALL SWIFT CLI

REF: https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/objectstorge_usingobjectstorage.html#using-swift-cli

STEP 1 - ************ MANDATORY *************
Generate a secret key, the longer the better.

$ swift post -m "Temp-URL-Key:2d2a3e9f12e87b1_SOMEKEY_2d2a3e9f12e87b1"

***You can retrieve it anytime by typing in the bash --> $ swift stat

---

STEP 2 - ************  OPTIONAL *************
Install dotenv package
$ npm install --save dotenv

STEP 3 - ************  OPTIONAL *************
Create a .env file
$ touch .env

STEP 4 - ************  OPTIONAL *************
Edit the .env file and put those values in and save the file.

**(ref. --> as per STEP 1)**

META_TEMP_URL_KEY=b463af8f_SOMEVALUEKEY_b463af8fb463af8f

**(ref. --> The projectid as per provided by the Bluemix Console)**

PROJECTID=50e8a0e8SOMEVALUEKEYbb463af8f

```
require('dotenv').config();

var crypto = require('crypto');

var META_TEMP_URL_KEY = process.env.META_TEMP_URL_KEY; // See Step 1
var baseUrl = 'https://dal.objectstorage.open.softlayer.com'; // Since my bucket is in DALLAS I am having this URL
var HTTPMethod = 'GET'; // Always GET - As the file has been already uploaded.
var containerName = 'expenses'; // Container Name as per in the Bluemix console - Ex: expenses
var objectName = 'report.pdf'; // The object filename - Ex: report.pdf
var seconds = 60; // Delay of the temporary URL to be valid.

var tempURL = getTempURL(baseUrl, HTTPMethod, containerName, objectName, seconds);
console.log(tempURL); // It should return in this case something like this:
// https://dal.objectstorage.open.softlayer.com/v1/AUTH_X0X0X0X0XX0X0XX0X0X/expenses/report.pdf?temp_url_sig=Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0Z0&temp_url_expires=1476243544

function getTempURL(baseUrl, HTTPMethod, metaTempURLKey, projectID, containerName, objectName, seconds) {

    var expires = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + seconds;
    var url = containerName + '/' + objectName;
    var method = HTTPMethod;
    var key = key;
    var objectPath = '/v1/AUTH_' + process.env.PROJECTID + '/' + url;
    var hmacBody = method + '\n' + expires + '\n' + objectPath;
    var sig = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(hmacBody).digest('hex');
    var tempURL = baseUrl + objectPath + '?temp_url_sig=' + sig + '&temp_url_expires=' + expires;

    return tempURL;
}
```

Comment: Well, 'can only be done'... not really, probably not via Bluemix Console, but you can simply code it yourself quite easily in any language following [this](https://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/object-storage-tempurl.html) E.g. in javascript, for which there are also libraries / code snippets available within github.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the necessary keys (application key, application secret key, consumer key) you can do this 'offline' (so not as a request to the respective swift openstack api) by coding it yourself or using a library for this. Since your looking for something that can be used in JS/Node, [this library](https://github.com/eswak/swift-temp-url) e.g. will be helpful.